# Attach a global onBeforeCall listener to all AJAX call except for one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having numerous AJAX call using JQuery. Among these is an AJAX call, let's say `auth()` that checks whether the user is currently logged to the system, idle, etc, and if not, will cause the page to redirect to the login page.

This `auth()` function is called every minute. Other than that usage, I want to call this function on before every other AJAX call that will be made— just to ensure that they are logged to perform a transaction.

I'm thinking of using the `beforeSend` property of `$.ajaxSetup` to achieve this, but won't it also be attached to `auth()` since it is also an AJAX call? I can confirmed this because I have tried using `beforeSend` and it throws an error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can I select all AJAX call (except for `auth()`) and attach it an *"onBeforeCall"* listener?

Comment: Authentication should be made on the Server-Side. Client-Side could be manipulated and bypass this call.

Comment: @Ori Yeah that's a given though I didn't do the previous codes. If an AJAX call has been made while there is no user currently logged, it will return a `XHR` of `http://localhost:8080/auth/login?targetUri=` instead. Though it doesn't mean that it will automatically be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Why cant you call auth() directly before all ajax calls? by setting auth() ajax call synchronous ?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru Because every page has at least 10+ different AJAX call and editing each to change it to `sychronous` will be troublesome.

Comment: Im not saying to change all ajax calls to sync ..only auth() call

Comment: @Gideon - the redirection on "User not logged in" scenario can also be implemented on the server side, as far as i know.

Comment: @MuraliMopuru Will still throw `RangeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overload the `ajax` method of jQuery:

```
var $ajax = $.ajax; // save old ajax method
$.ajax = function () {
    if (!auth())
        throw 'NOT AUTHENTIFICATED!'; // or whatever
    return $ajax.apply(this, arguments); // if auth() passed call the old ajax method and return it so the whole jQuery API works...
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do is to write a generic function which will act as a proxy to all of your AJAX calls. Something like this:

```
var ajax = {
    send: function(url,type,success,error,data){
        $.ajax{
           url:url,
           method:type,
           beforeSend: function(xhr, opts){
              if(!auth()) {
                 xhr.abort();
              }
           }
           success:success,
           error:error
        }
    }
}
```

Call all of your AJAX calls this way:

`ajax.send(url,type,success,error,data);    //Pass success and error as functions`